# How to public sign a project with MSBuild

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

I have a C# .NET Framework project which I sign using a `.pfx` file on my local system. In the `.csproj` file the following properties are set:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <SignAssembly>true</SignAssembly>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup>
  <AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile>keyfile.pfx</AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile>
</PropertyGroup>
```

This file is part of an open source project. I'm trying to create a pipeline which runs on certain commits. When I commit something, the original `*.pfx` can be installed using the password which is stored as a GitHub secret. The problem is that when forked repos make a pull request, the pipeline fails, because the GitHub secrets are not available to them.

Long story short, I found out that I can use [public signing](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/docs/project/public-signing.md) for this purpose. However, when I try to build my project using

```
msbuild src\TcBlackCore\TcBlackCore.csproj -t:Rebuild -p:DelaySign=false -p:PublicSign=true -p:Configuration=Release -p:Platform=AnyCPU -p:TreatWarningsAsErrors=true
```

I get the following error:

> CS7102: Compilation options 'PublicSign' and 'CryptoKeyContainer' can't both be specified at the same time

I couldn't find any information on this error code except for [one GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/23326) which mentions:

> ERR_MutuallyExclusiveOptions  CS7102

What are the mutually exclusive options here? The `DelaySign` should be set to the [docs](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/docs/project/public-signing.md#msbuild-and-compiler-tooling-support). And what should I do to get the public signing to work such that forked repos can be build?

```
> msbuild -version
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.9.21+g9802d43bc3 for .NET Framework
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with public sign is that **while the compiler applies a public key, is doesn't actually signs the assembly**. It is like a 'mark' on the assembly.

In your case, you cannot use both `CryptoKeYContainer` and `PublicSign` at the same time because they are doing almost identical things, thus the compiler prompts the error.

for your purpose I would recommend using the `DelaySign` - as Microsoft docs states:

> Use `DelaySign` - If you want a fully signed assembly. Use `DelaySign`
> if you only want to place the public key in the assembly

For reference the tag is:

`<DelaySign>true</DelaySign>`

Comment: Thanks it worked! Although the unit tests now do not run. I'll remove the whole signed business. It is causing so many headaches.